# How to avoid image to be cut at the bottom of a pdf page when using html, xmlworker and itext?

Tags: html, image, pdf, xmlworker

I'm currently developing an application where there's a form that is supposed to be used by users to type rich text, which must be later converted to PDF.
I used [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) for the textarea. So there is HTML code behind the text typed. Then, I used `XMLWorker` to convert the text to PDF.

But before converting it, I should dynamically include an image at the end of the text, and I use `<img sr=""/>` tag for that. But now the problem is when the text is long, the image is cut at the bottom of the page, instead of going to the next page.

I thought about another solution which is adding the image on the PDF as one can do with itext Image class.
But when doing like that, I don't know which code to write to dynamically put the image on the next page when there is no more enough space on the page for it after the text.
I would be very glad if someone can help me fix that.

Here is my current code:

```
public class PdfMaker {
  public String generatePdf( Theme theme, Cible cible, int i ) {

    String chaine = null;
    String new_chaine = null;

    if ( theme.getCorps() != null ) {
        chaine =
                "<html><head><meta content=\"charset=UTF-8\"/></head><body>" + theme.getCorps()
                        + "<br/><p/><img src=\" " + Constantes.BANNERS_PATH + Constantes.PREF_BANNER + i
                        + Constantes.SUFF_BANNER
                        + " \"/></body></html>";

        // On remplace les patterns contenus dans le texte
        new_chaine = remplacerPatterns( chaine, cible );
    }
    // On génère un nom pour le PDF à créer
    String outfilename = genOutputName();
    try {
        // On crée un objet document
        Document document = new Document();
        // On crée un PDF portant le nom généré dans le chemin défini
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance( document, new FileOutputStream( Constantes.PDFs_PATH + "\\"
                + outfilename ) );
        document.open();
        // On transpose le texte (en HTML) sur le PDF
        XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml( writer, document, new StringReader( new_chaine ) );

        System.out.println( "pdf généré" );
        // System.out.println( theme.getCorps().length() );
        document.close();
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return outfilename;
  }

  private static String genOutputName() {
    return Long.toString( System.currentTimeMillis() ) + ".pdf";
  }

  public String remplacerPatterns( String texte, Cible cible ) {
    String texte1 = null;
    texte1 = texte.replaceAll( "\\{nom\\}", cible.getNom() )
            .replaceAll( "\\{prenom\\}", cible.getPrenom() );
    return texte1;
  }
}
```

PS: I'm not English native speaker and I might haven't found the right words to express myself. So if there's something not clear in what I wrote, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I finally found a way to fix it. I just had to surround the <img> tag with <p> tag. Then, the image dynamically goes to next page or stays on the current one whether there is enough space or not.